# ASP.net vNext and Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Is it possible to run EF6 under the pre-release ASP.net vNext? EF7 doesn't have some features I need, but I would like to prototype my application in .NET Core.

I'm getting the following error:

```
FileLoadException: A strongly-named assembly is required. 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044) Unknown location

FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly
'EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' or one of its dependencies. 
A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)
```

I know that .NET Core doesn't support strongly-named assemblies, but as far as I know I'm running the server under the aspnet50 framework rather than aspnetcore50.

My project.json looks like this:

```
{
    "webroot": "wwwroot",
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.1",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta3",
        /* "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim": "6.0.0-beta3", */
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.Cookies": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta3",
        "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta3",
        "Tricycle.SqlPlatform.EntityFramework": "1.0.0-*"
    },
    "commands": {
        /* Change the port number when you are self hosting this application */
        "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Hosting --server Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener --server.urls http://localhost:5000",
        "gen": "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGeneration",
    },
    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "Tricycle.Studio.ContentManager.Client": "1.0.0-*"
            }
        },
        //"aspnetcore50": { }
    },
    "exclude": [
        "wwwroot",
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components"
    ],
    "bundleExclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "**.kproj",
        "**.user",
        "**.vspscc"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "postrestore": [ "npm install" ],
        "prepare": [ "grunt bower:install" ]
    }
}
```

The EF classes are defined in a separate project (Tricycle.Studio.ContentManager.Client) with the following project.json:

```
{
    "version": "1.0.0-*",
    "dependencies": {
        "EntityFramework": "6.1.1",
    },

    "frameworks": {
        "aspnet50": {
            "dependencies": {
                "System.Data.Common": "1.0.0-beta2",
                "System.Data.SqlClient": "1.0.0-beta2"
            }
        },
        //"aspnetcore50" : {
        //    "dependencies": {
        //        "System.Runtime": "4.0.20-beta-22523"
        //    }
        //}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot use `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` with EF6 because it depends on EF7.

Based on your `project.json` file, the runtime will load both EF6 and EF7 (because of Identity). The behavior is unpredictable.

Also, do not mix `beta2` and `beta3` packages. That's guaranteed trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Removing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework seems to have fixed it. Regarding beta2/3 - those packages only seem to be available in beta2.

Comment: Ah, nice find, @Victor. All the new toys in startup made me overlook this. +1